# Subtracting the second MIN value from a SUM

Tags: sql-server

What I want to do is this:

```
SELECT
    RaceResults.IdPilot,
    SUM(RaceResults.Score)-MIN(RaceResults.Score)-MIN2(RaceResults.Score) AS TotalScore
FROM RaceResults
GROUP BY RaceResults.IdPilot
```

How can i get the second minimum value (MIN2 in the above code) from the column Score?

Comment: please show sample data and desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional sum() based off the window function Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([IdPilot] int,[Score] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,15)
,(1,15)
,(1,20)
,(1,50)   -- The sum of example is 100 and the bottom 2 equal 30


Select A.IdPilot
      ,TotalScore = sum(Score)-sum(case when rn<=2 then Score end)
 From (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By idPilot Order by Score)
         From  @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By A.IdPilot
```

**Returns**

```
IdPilot   TotalScore
1         70
```

Comment: Min2 must be 20 I think, so the result must be 65.

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan Min2 in this case is 15.

Comment: @dev Happy it helped

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan I crafted the sample data to illustrate ties so by using row_number() rather than dense_rank(), we would get the correct results